# How to make jagged geometry smooth/diagonal?

Tags: modeling, workflow, topology, geometry

Often times I select faces from my character's body and then duplicated them and grow them up in order to create clothes. However, sometimes this results in jagged clothes with hard edges. Is there a way to select all the jagged corners and moved them so that the clothes become smooth?

or any other suggestions to make clothes that are not jagged?

Here is what I mean. I selected some faces from the purple body and then duplicated them into the yellow pant (The gap is not part of the problem, it's just part of the style). The problem is the jagged geometry that makes it look "pixelated".

[image]

Comment: so why do you choose this strange method? Also it needs a lot of faces, you could reduce the topology a lot with another method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad topology with high poly count and work with this becomes hard and more inefficient.

You will need to adjust many things manually because the tools works based on topology of your mesh and if it has a bad topology, then, the tools have bad results too:

But using the **Relax** tool from the **Loop Tools** addon maybe you can solve your problem:

Loop Tools addon already inside in blender and to enable it go to **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Addons** and search for "loopTools"
[image]

Now you can use the **Relax** tool:
[image]

**N panel** > **Edit** > **LoopTools** > **Relax**

Comment: Thanks that worked well enough! I appreciate your honesty, I didn't realize it was bad topology. I just got started with Blender. My model used to be a lot lower poly but I applied a surface subdivide modifier because I thought it would make it look more realistic. If I didn't subdivide, wouldn't the pants be even more jagged/pixelated? How should I approach modelling then?

Comment: You're welcome, search for some tutorials about body topology and edge flow/edge loops and parametric (non-destructive) modeling. This video show some details about:   [Intro To 3D Art - Lesson 3 - The Body, Pixar Style Topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5G9ziFbJJmM) he is using Maya but you can absorb the principles and apply later in blender

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be a bad idea, but you could possibly get away with using the triangulate modifier [blender doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/triangulate.html) and then select the triangles.